# PHP Minus 2 variables for value

Tags: php

I have a page that when data is posted to it inserts the value into my DB.

Im trying to get a sum of all the values from the DB before hand, then insert the value, and then take the SUM away from the value inserted if this makes sense?

```
$totalquery = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(bill) FROM `outgoings` WHERE outgoings.user_id = '$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
$totalresult = mysql_fetch_array($totalquery);          
$uid = $_SESSION['oauth_id'];
$id = $_POST['col-id'];
$sanitized_monthly_income = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['monthly-income']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO income (id, user_id, monthly_income) VALUES ('$id', '$uid', '$sanitized_monthly_income') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE monthly_income = VALUES(monthly_income)");
echo $sanitized_monthly_income - $totalresult["SUM(bill)"];
```

This is the error I receive though

> Notice: Undefined variable: uid in update_salary.php on line 18

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Your code appears to contian SQL injection vulnerabilities. :-(

Answer (score 4):

You're using `$uid` before it is assigned:

```
 $totalquery = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(bill) FROM `outgoings`
                            WHERE outgoings.user_id = '$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
 #                                                     ^^^^
 # then later ...

 $uid = $_SESSION['oauth_id'];
```

You probably need to move the assignment above the line where you try to access the value.